# Infinite Money Glitch - Red Dead Redemption 2

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

## Background Info:

So I was looking up tips and tricks that I could do in Red Dead Redemption 2 and noticed there’s one for [infinite money](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.newsweek.com/red-dead-2-redemption-gold-bar-glitch-infinite-money-1193816%3famp=1) . The problem is I already raided and found this gold bar earlier before I knew about this and sold it.

## Question(s):

1. Is it still possible to use this glitch?
2. If I can’t use it, would I have to redo a whole new game?
3. Are there any other hacks that can give infinite money? (I know about treasure maps but I’m referring to anything else)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the infinite money glitch is still available. If you already got the gold bar in Limpany, there are a handful of other gold bars you can use to exploit this glitch. Here's a [list of their locations](https://www.gameskinny.com/wk78u/red-dead-redemption-2-infinite-money-glitch-with-gold-bars).

There's no word on when -- or if -- this glitch is going to be fixed, so I would take advantage of it now. Knowing Rockstar, it will probably be patched relatively soon.